# Check a tuple for at least 5 consecutive numbers

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I have a tuple A and I would like to check if it contains at least 5 consecutive numbers somewhere. What is the most time efficient way to do this?

A= (1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12) -->TRUE

This is used in a montecarlo siulation to check if a 7 card poker hand contain a straight.

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a sorted tuple of 7 different integers. If there are 5 integers in series, i.e. (n, n+1, n+2, n+3, n+4), they must start on position 0, 1 or 2 and end on position 4, 5, or 6 respectively.

```
straight = any(a[4+i] - a[i] == 4 for i in (0,1,2))
```

Update: If the sequence length is not fixed:
(suggested by tobias_k in comments)

```
straight = any(a[4+i] - a[i] == 4 for i in range(len(a)-4))
```

Comment: The tuple contains between 5 and 7 numbers. How can I adjust the (0,1,2) accordingly?

Comment: This only works is there are no duplicate numbers, but in a poker hand, there can be duplicate values, e.g. `[1,1,1,2,2,5,5]` would yield `True` using your algorithm.

Comment: Yes but in my algorithm duplicates are filtered out, as a result there are sometimes only 5 digits. Could I replace the (0,1,2) with another loop? For j in range(len(A)-4))) doesn't work but it must be sometime similar?

Comment: @Nicolas Well, if you filtered out any dupes, then this should work. You could replace the `(0, 1, 2)` by, e.g. `range(len(a) - 4)`

Comment: That works well, only problem is how, can I find out which digit was the highest one in the order? Since I'm using 'any' this information is getting lost. Any suggestions how to get the index of the highest number that was in the consecutive order?

Comment: @Nicolas: this could be done in a for loop looping in a reversed order. Your question is currently on hold because it became a moving target. Please provide a complete information about the data and about the consecutive numbers problem.

Comment: I think the problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a simple one-liner for this, but you basically just have to loop the elements in the list and check whether it's one more than the last one, and return True if the running count reaches 5. You also have to consider the case that there are two cards with the same value.

```
def has_straight(values, req=5):
    last = count = None
    for x in values:
        if x - 1 == last:
            count += 1  # one more on the straight
        elif x == last:
            pass        # same value as before
        else:
            count = 1   # start a new straight
        if count >= req:
            return True
        last = x
    return False
```

Some examples:

```
has_straight((1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12))  # no straight -> False
has_straight((1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12))   # straight in middle -> True
has_straight((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 12))  # at beginning -> True
has_straight((1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)) # at very end -> True
has_straight((1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5))    # straight with dupes -> True
```

Complexity would be O(n), which is as good as it could possibly get, as you have to check each number.